# Radio button and its associated values in html table (corresponding row) to a servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Report</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
    <form action=allrep method="get">
          <H1>Report</H1>
        <% 
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fees";
        String user = "root";
        String passswd = "password";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,passswd);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultset = 
        statement.executeQuery("select * from fee1") ; 
        %>
        <TABLE BORDER="1">
            <TR>
            <th>Select</th>
            <TH>Id</TH>
            <TH>Name</TH>
            <TH>Fee</TH>
            <TH>Course</TH>
            <TH>Occupation</TH>
            <TH>Balance</TH>
            <TH>Date</TH>
            </TR>
           <%     while (resultset.next()) { %>
           <TR>
           <td><input type="radio" name="setval"></td>
           <TD> <%= resultset.getString(5) %> </TD>
           <TD contenteditable="true"> <%= resultset.getString(1) %> </TD>
           <input type="hidden" value="<%= resultset.getString(1) %>" name="fname">
           <TD contenteditable="true"> <%= resultset.getString(2) %> </TD>
           <TD contenteditable="true"> <%= resultset.getString(3) %> </TD>
           <TD contenteditable="true"> <%= resultset.getString(4) %> </TD>
           <TD contenteditable="true"> <%= resultset.getString(6) %> </TD>
           <TD contenteditable="true"> <%= resultset.getString(7) %> </TD>
           </TR>
       <% 
           } 
       %>
       </TABLE>  <BR><BR>
        <input type="submit" value="Update Record">  
        </form>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here's the servlet code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class allrep
 */
public class allrep extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public allrep() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String radio=request.getParameter("setval");

        if(radio!=null)
        {
            String fname=request.getParameter("fname");
            System.out.println("you've ticked");
            System.out.println(fname);
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

In here regardless of the radio button the fname only prints the value from the first row.

When I press the second radio button I want to get the value of that particular row, but I'm only getting the value of the first row when `System.out.printf` is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind radiobuttons is that you provide a different value to each `<input type="radio name="setval>` element by setting the `value` attribute. The browser then puts the value of the selected radiobutton into parameter of the defined name.

So use the radiobutton like this and remove the hidden parameter:

```
<input type="radio" name="setval" value="<%= resultset.getString(1) %>" />
```

Then retrieve it:

```
String fname=request.getParameter("setval");
```

Comment: can i apply the same for other fields as well?there are name ,fee course occupation and balance

Comment: The best practice is to set the id on the radiobutton then use the id to get the complete data set in the servlet. If you send all data through the form request, it is possible for any user to alter the data by altering the request. This can pose a severe security threat depending on what your servlet is going to do.

Comment: oh yes that's a great idea ! thank you .you made my day.!

Comment: You're welcome. If you are happy with the answer, don't forget to accept it. It's important for the rating algorithms of StackExchange. (And i get points ;-))